# Point translation ortghogonally to the line

Tags: c++, opengl, math, linear-algebra

I am currently working on a project of drawing thick polylines and I am using interpolation in OpenGL. I managed to calculate all the necessary points but I need to draw two more points. I need to translate one point orthogonally to the line connecting two points. The scatch below shows what are the points. Point L is to be translated for the distance between L and nJ orthogonally to the line AB (B is the central point). Similar thing is with translation to the nK.

[image]

I have written the code:

```
float alpha = atan2(B.y - A.y,B.x - A.x) - deg90;
float alpha2 = atan2(C.y - B.y, C.x - B.x) - deg90;


nJ.x = L.x + w*cos(alpha); // w is distance between A1 and A2
nJ.y = L.y + w*sin(alpha);
nK.x = L.x + w*cos(alpha2);
nK.y = L.y + w*sin(alpha2);
```

The code works only for some points, not all. I need to fix + sing in above calculations of nJ and nK, but I do not know how. Anyone having suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

First you need the left-hand-side function:

```
lhs(v) = [-v.y, v.x]
```

This turns a vector 90 degrees counter-clockwise.

Now you need the turn function:

```
turn(u, v, w) = sign(lhs(v - u), w - v)
```

If you have a polyline from `u` to `v` to `w`, `turn(u,v,w)` tells you whether it's a left turn (counter-clockwise turn) (positive), right turn (clockwise turn) (negative), or colinear (0).

There are four infinite lines in your picture that run parallel to `ab` and `bc`, with a distance of `w` between each pair.

The lines on the lower part are:

```
f(s) = (a + 0.5 * w * normalize(lhs(b - a))) + (b - a) * s
g(t) = (b + 0.5 * w * normalize(lhs(c - b))) + (c - b) * t
```

You want to find the intersection of the two lines; i.e., you want to solve for `s` and `t` in `f(s) = g(t)`. This is just a system of two linear equations with two unknowns.

The solution is your point `L = f(s) = g(t)` in the picture.

To compute `I` you can use the exact same idea:

```
f(s) = (a - 0.5 * w * normalize(lhs(b - a))) + (b - a) * s
g(t) = (b - 0.5 * w * normalize(lhs(c - b))) + (c - b) * t
```

Solve for `I = f(s) = g(t)`.

## Update

Once you have `L` you can compute `Kn` and `Jn` as follows.

```
Kn = L - w * normalize(lhs(b - a))
Jn = L - w * normalize(lhs(c - b))
```

In computational geometry code, trigonometry is usually a code smell - it's not always wrong, but it usually is wrong. Try to stick to linear algebra.

Comment: This was an exhaustive answer, but not for my question. As said I have points A1, A2, C1, C2, J, K, I and L. What I need to calculate is Jn (in code nJ) and Kn.

Comment: @M_global The phrasing in the question wasn't crystal clear... I'll update with that part (it's easy).

Comment: Thaks this was very helpful and I am sorry if my question was not crystal clear. Again I have done what you suggested but it works only for some, not all points.

Comment: Also, I think you changed Kn and Jn.